# How to draw a line.new from start and end of month and week in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Need Help in pine script to draw a line.new from start to end of the month as well as week. My calculation for the start of the month week is not working well.  Help me here.

`enter code here`

```
 todaystart = timestamp(y, m, d, 00, 00)
 start = if pivottimeframe == 'D'
    todaystart
 else if pivottimeframe == 'W'
    todaystart - (dayofweek(time)) * 86400000
 else if pivottimeframe == 'M'
    todaystart - (dayofmonth(time)) * 86400000
else
   todaystart


end = if pivottimeframe == 'D'
   start + 86400000
else if pivottimeframe == 'W'
   start + 86400000 * 7
else if pivottimeframe == 'M'
   start + 86400000 * 30
else
   start + 86400000
```

Comment: Assuming it is the first day of the month, it looks like would start at midnight and still subtract a whole day in the end.

Try `todaystart - (dayofmonth(time) - 1) * 86400000` instead, same for the week.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding fixed amount of milliseconds, which could vary from month to month, use the `request.security()` function call with the `time` and `time_close` variables from the monthly chart.

The script below plots a horizontal line at the level of 10(you haven't specified y-axis location) from the beginning of the current month till the next one, it updates on the monthly change and moves the line. Same logic for the weekly, daily etc.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Monthly horizontal line", overlay = false)

[monthStart, monthEnd] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', [time, time_close])

var line myLine = line.new(monthStart, 10, monthEnd, 10, xloc = xloc.bar_time)

if ta.change(monthStart)
    line.set_x1(myLine, monthStart)
    line.set_x2(myLine, monthEnd)
```